# Simple JavaScript on Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, haml

I want to create my first javascript program. There are 2 checkboxes and when I check the first one, I want the second one to be checked too.
Can someone please tell me why this is not working?

```
.filters#filters
  = render "sharedStuff/search"
    .check_box{:style => "border-bottom: 5px silver dotted;"}
      %div{:style => "float:right;"}

  %div
    = check_box_tag "Black",false, false
    Black
  %div
    = check_box_tag "Red", false, false
    Red

  :javascript
    jQuery(function($) {
      $('#Black').change(Black);
    }); 
    function Black(){
      if($('Black').checked){
        $('Red').checked = true
        }};
```

I actually copy-pasted from a project where this piece of code was working. Am I missing something? Do I need to change something else somewhere else? Or it was a prone copy-paste. This code segment was in a bigger project. Maybe I am missing some tags etc. ?

Comment: What language are you writing in? Because this is not javascript, and it is not correct jQuery at all. Where is your else after the if?

Comment: Do you not find it confusing to have everything named either Black or Red?

Comment: Haml+java script. and for your if question, i don't have an else. don't think i have to.

Comment: ehehe it's a bit confusing right. just wanted to give simple names

Comment: I am hoping that Haml is a typo. If you are writing in HTML and javascript, using jQuery, than I believe you need an else. But even if you don't NEED one, it is just good programming practice.

Comment: Please google for haml

Comment: @TJonS http://haml.info

Comment: Oh! I thought it was an "HTML" typo. My error. It might have helped if you said that in the beginning:)

Comment: @TJonS I don't consider it a good programming practice to include an `else` clause if it is not needed - Where did you get this idea from?

Comment: sammy, have you researched how to use CoffeeScript yet? if you use rails.. i'd consider using CoffeeScript.. it's much cleaner!

Comment: The fact that I have never seen an if without an else :)

Comment: I have seen this thousands of times. The fact that you haven't seen it doesn't make it a good programming practice.

Answer (score 1):

Your Haml, js looks fine except this piece:

```
function Black(){
  if($('Black').checked){
  $('Red').checked = true
}};
```

in here, you need a css selector.  as it's written here, you are looking for,

```
<Black />
```

and

```
<Red />
```

what you want is `<input id='Black' />`

so specify the id's

```
function Black(){
  if($('input#Black').is(':checked'))
    $('input#Red').prop('checked', 'checked');
  else
    $('input#Red').prop('checked', '');
}};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but no luck